# Php cant write files in tmp

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'am sorry for my english skills, but i am completely stack and need help. I have old developers server and new, also i got php code -

```
<?php

// error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

print '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
print '</pre>';

?>
<form action="/test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="preview" class="text" size="80" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

on the old server it create files ok, but on the new server this did not work.I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: this code doesnt create anything

Comment: can you post "create files" code part please? This code will tell us nothing

Comment: You have to use `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: this is upload files page code, looks like i cant exaplain correctly sorry

Comment: You need to post the code of `test.php` file

Comment: Code in main post is code of test.php

Comment: That's not possible, this code doesn't upload any file

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your new server is a *nix system.

When the browser sends the uploaded file to the server it is initially placed into a `tmp` folder.

When your `test.php` does the `move_uploaded_file()` it moves it from this `tmp` folder to the correct place for your site.

Check the php.ini parameter `upload_tmp_dir` and then check that whatever folder that points to has the correct access rights for your Apache web server account to write to it.

**After Your Comment**

*FROM THE MANUAL*

```
upload_tmp_dir string

The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. 
Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. 
If not specified PHP will use the system's default.

If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the 
system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the 
system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.
```

So if you have no setting for `upload_tmp_dir` it will be using the system default temporary folder. That **probably** does not have the correct settings to allow your web server account access.

Also you will not see the file that was uploaded in the tmp folder because PHP destroys it when the script that is supposed to be processsing it onto the correct place from the tmp folder finishes. For obvious security reasons!
Or in fact in your case as it cannot write to that directory it will never get there because that is your basic problem.

Comment: It does not appear in the folder tmp, upload_tmp_dir is commented on each server. I try set upload_tmp_dir to /tmp/jopa or else so it have no effect

Comment: Use another solutions to test upload files - http://www.dzone.com/snippets/very-simple-php-file-upload
When i use it i get php err 7 - UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
php.ini in default configuration

Comment: Yes... So as I said, its PHP that is seeing the error before you get to do anything with the file. PHP cannot place the file in the tmp folder, so it has almost got to be a privileges problem on whereever the tmp folder is on your new server!!!! If all else fails **R.T.F.M** http://www.php.net//manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I understand but looks like cant explain my situation, if i change tmp in htaccess or php.ini as example to /home/tmp with right permissions it works! but php cant write in 777 /tmp and i dont understand whats going wrong. I am very very sorry for my english skills, my fault that I can not explain properly.